# Error during the usage of of size() function in vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

So I've started learning vectors for the first time and wrote a simple program which goes like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> g1; 
    int n;
    cout<<"enter values"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cin>>n;
        g1.push_back(n);
    } while (n);
    cout<<"Vector values are: "<<endl;
    for(auto i=g1.begin(); i<g1.size();i++)
    cout<<*i<<endl;
}
```

When I try executing it, an error shows up saying "type mismatch" at the g1.size() part. Why exactly does this happen? I used the auto keyword for the iterator involved and assumed there wouldn't be any problem?

Comment: `g1.begin()` yields a `std::vector<int>::iterator` not a `size_t`.

Comment: `for (auto&& x : g1) cout << x << "\n";` would be preferable for the last loop: 1. for-range instead of mucking about with the details, and getting them wrong. 2. `auto&&` to still avoid copies on principle, not that it matters for `int`. 3. `"\n"` to avoid costly flushing.

Comment: Don't describe errors so vaguely. Repeat the message.

Comment: My apologies for the vague error description. This is literally the first ever question I've asked online

Comment: @vijay You just need to change `i<g1.size()` to `i != g1.end()` to fix your loop condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the bad side of using `auto`. If you have no idea what the result of `auto` is, you get no idea why it is something totally different you expect!

`std::vector::begin` delivers a `std::vector::iterator` and you can't compare it against an `size_type` value which is a result of `std::vector::size`. This type is typically `std::size_t`

You have to compare against another iterator which is the representation of the end of the vector like:

```
for(auto i = g1.begin(); i != g1.end(); i++)
```

Comment: Correct. An iterator is an abstract pointer. It doesn't make sense to ask if a pointer is less than an integer.

Comment: OP seemed aware that `begin()` would return an iterator

Comment: `std::vector<T>::size()` doesn't yield an `int` type. Be precise please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is std::size_t not an integer value? Changed it but it is more precise but not easier to understand.

Comment: @Klaus It's an `unsigned long`, which can make a big difference. Especially in loops I often see people wondering why `size_t` values  compared as being less than `0` won't behave as they think it should (ignoring the compiler warnings of course). Otherwise I hadn't nickpicked.

Comment: There is a world of difference between an integer value and an `int` value. The latter has a known type and is in a specified range. Only Java has `int` boxed as `Integer` just to muddle the water.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `unsigned long`? In theory, `size_t` could be an `unsigned char`, and hilarity ensues.

Comment: @Deduplicator Most of the time it's an `unsigned long`, yes.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three ways to iterate through the contents of a vector.

You can use an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    std::cout  << vec[i] << '\n';
```

You can use iterators:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
```

You can use a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto val : vec)
    std::cout << Val <<'\n';
```

The latter two can be used with any container.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with ranged based for loops yet  but that seems to be the easiest way to iterate..

Answer (score 1):

`g1.begin()` returns an *iterator* to the 1st element, whereas `g1.size()` returns the *number* of elements.  You can't compare an iterator to a size, which is why you are getting the error.  It has nothing to do with your use of `auto`, it has to do with you comparing 2 different things that are unrelated to each other.

You need to change your loop to compare your `i` iterator to the vector's `end()` iterator, eg:

```cpp
for(auto i = g1.begin(); i != g1.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << endl;
```

Or, simply use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead, which uses iterators internally:

```cpp
for(auto i : g1)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `size()` then use indexes with the vector's `operator[]`, instead of using iterators, eg:

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < g1.size(); ++i)
    cout << g1[i] << endl;
```